# case of pair - match only the same value

Tags: haskell

I have following type:

```
MyData = MI Integer | MD Double | MC Char.
```

Now, I would like to be able do following thing:

```
(MI _, MI _) -> "ok, these are the same value"  
(MI _, MD _) -> "fail, first is MI, and second is MD"
```

How to do it ?  As you think, I don't want write too much cases...
Can you recommend me some way ?

Comment: what is your problem you only need to wrap this in a function definition - (remember to use `=` not `->`, start with writing your type signature - and maybe have a [`lyah`](http://learnyouahaskell.com) open to acompany you

Comment: btw - your type definition is wrong - you need to put `data` in front of that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution in "*pure*" Haskell (that is without much language extensions, etc.) would be to first map the `MyData` to a <`MyDataType`> (which can for instance be an `Integer`) item and compare the types. The advantage is that you can perform other comparisons on the type. For example:

```
import Data.Function(on)

data MyData = MI Integer | MD Double | MC Char

myDataType :: MyData -> Integer
myDataType (MI _) = 0
myDataType (MD _) = 1
myDataType (MC _) = 2

areEqualTypes :: (MyData,MyData) -> Bool
areEqualTypes (a,b) = (==) `on` myDataType
```

altough for this case there is not much added value, if you later want to check for a tuple of three whether two types are equal, it will result in less code. For example:

```
atLeastOneEqualType :: (MyData,MyData,MyData) -> Bool
atLeastOneEqualType (a,b,c) = ta == tb || ta == tc || tb == tc
    where ta = myDataType a
          tb = myDataType b
          tc = myDataType c
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve a calculation with a notion of failure to use `Either String x` as a result type.

In this case a function

```
data MyData = MI Integer | MD Double | MC Char
            deriving (Show)

equivalence :: MyData -> MyData -> Either String Bool
equivalence (MI _) (MI _) = Right True
equivalence (MD _) (MD _) = Right True
equivalence (MC _) (MC _) = Right True
equivalence a       b     = Left $ "Type mismatch: " ++ show (a,b)
```

for now this is rather uninteresting but a future version could be

```
equivalence :: MyData -> MyData -> Either String Bool
equivalence (MI a) (MI b) = Right $ a == b
equivalence (MD a) (MD b) = Right $ a == b
equivalence (MC a) (MC b) = Right $ a == b
equivalence     a      b  = Left $ "Type mismatch: " ++ show (a,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably easiest is the most straightforward way, you just need to write four conditions

```
equalType :: (MyData, MyData) -> Bool
equalType (MC _, MC _) = True
equalType (MI _, MI _) = True
equalType (MD _, MD _) = True
equalType _ = False
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cname_MyData :: MyData -> String
cname_MyData (MI _) = "MI"
cname_MyData (MD _) = "MD"    
cname_MyData (MC _) = "MC"

doThing :: MyData -> MyData -> Either String a
doThing (MI i1) (MI i2) = Right (...)
doThing (MD d1) (MD d2) = Right (...)
doThing (MC c1) (MC c2) = Right (...)
doThing x1 x2 = Leftt ("Tried to doThing with " ++ 
      cname_MyData x1 ++" and " ++ cname_MyData x2)
```